# using index twice in a loop

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm trying to figure out the reason why I can't use an index twice in a loop,
there should be something very simple that I'm missing.
the structure of the code is like this:

```html
<p id="one">test</p>

<p class="two">a</p>
<p class="two">b</p>
<p class="two">c</p>

<script>
var one = document.getElementById("one");
var two = document.getElementsByClassName("two");
var i = 0;
while (i < two.length) {
  two[i].addEventListener("click", function() {two[i].innerHTML = one.innerHTML;});
  i++;
}
</script>
```

any suggestion will be appreciated =)

Comment: Use `let`: https://jsfiddle.net/p4kb16d7/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when

```
function() {two[i].innerHTML = one.innerHTML;});
```

runs, the loop will have already completed, so `i` will be `two.length`.  You need to either use a closure:

```
while (i < two.length) {
    (function(i) {
        two[i].addEventListener("click", function() {two[i].innerHTML = one.innerHTML;});
    )(i);
    i++;
}
```

or use a different type of loop and use `let`:

```
for(let i = 0; i < two.length; i++){
    two[i].addEventListener("click", function() {two[i].innerHTML = one.innerHTML;});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is that by the time the event handler is running (onclick), the value of `i` has been changed/lost.

If you replace this line:
`two[i].addEventListener("click", function() {two[i] = one.innerHTML;});`
with
`two[i].addEventListener("click", function() {this.innerHTML = one.innerHTML;});`
it should work correctly.  "this" in the new version refers to the element that was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<p id="one">test</p>

<p class="two">a</p>
<p class="two">b</p>
<p class="two">c</p>

<script>
var one = document.getElementById("one");
var two = document.getElementsByClassName("two");
var i = 0;
while (i < two.length) {
    two[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
       this.innerHTML = one.innerHTML;
    });
    i++;
}
</script>
```